# Log post data using AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am new to AWS Lambda. I got a working model of lambda function which logs the json data to cloudwatch and also S3 bucket.

This is the function :

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var param = {Bucket: 'test', Key: 'test123', Body: event.name};
    console.log("EVENT DATA :" + param.Body);
    s3.upload(param, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data);           // successful response

        console.log('actually done!');
        context.done();
    });
    console.log('done?');
};
```

This is my json data :

```
{
  "name": "XYZ ABC",
  "value": 123
}
```

How should I push the whole JSON data given above to S3 and CloudFront logs rather than just event.name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `event.name` to `JSON.stringify(event)`. If you get `[object Object]` somewhere, change it to `JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)`

Comment: I tried that earlier. It does not work. EVENT DATA :[object Object] gets logged and i get exception while uploading the data to S3. Exception is [Error: Unsupported body payload object] 'Error: Unsupported body payload object\n at ManagedUpload.self.fillQueue